# "Твоё счастье" - фонетическое слово?

Tags: орфоэпия

Продолжая тему расстановки ударений в поэтической речи.
Вот пример для анализа:

```
Всё пройдет! «Будет день - будет пища...» -  /-//-//-/- амфм, 90%  
Ты стоишь у черты. На пороге                 --/--/--/- анап  
Твоё счастье застряло неслышно,              --/--/--/- анап  
Выгоняя за дверь все тревоги...              --/--/--/- анап
```

Хотя первая строка – почти чистый амфимакр, но стих явно написан 3-стопным анапестом (мы, вроде, договорились, что амфимакр с анапестом дружат).
Но вот в 3-й строке я смухлевал: в начале графического отображения ритма формально было "-//", т.е. стопа бакхия, который тут совсем не к месту и создаёт сбой ритма.
Я счёл такую подтасовку имеющей право на существование. Чтобы не мешало "ё", которое безударным не бывает, я записал в начале строки фонетическое слово "твойосчастье". "Покатал на языке" – вроде, таки это фонетическое слово, оба "о" в его начале редуцируются.
Но вот прав ли я?

Answer (score 3):

Это не подтасовка, это допустимо в поэтической речи - при чтении для сохранения нужного ритма некоторые ударные слоги читаются как безударные или с побочным ударением, как одно фонетическое слово.В данной строфе явно просматривается анапест во всех строках:369//369//369//369.Видимо, автор применил звукопись, чтобы создать иллюзию "уговора"-кто-то или внутренний голос уговаривает, внушает, что это пройдёт. Ударение не на том, что ВСЁ, а на том, что ПРОЙДЁТ.Не на БУДЕТ, а на ДЕНЬ и ПИЩА. Что-то вроде спондея, добавочного ударения, на котором мы не делаем акцента.

Comment: С первой строкой понятно - сверхсхемные ударения идут в стопах перед безударными слогами. Но вот в первой стопе третьей строки формально имеем "-//" (безударный-ударный-ударный). Моя подтасовка состоит в том, что я счёл "мЪjАща́с'т'jЭ" фонетическим словом со структурой "--/-". Вопрос - насколько это правомерно?

Comment: Я же на этот вопрос и ответила: правомерно, именно так и надо читать. Вы поняли мысль автора.

Comment: При всём моём уважении к замыслу автора, создавшего этот стих, меня больше интересует сам принцип. А если было бы  
     "В углу счастье застряло неслышно"  -//--/--/-  
Тут, вроде, фонетическое слово не вытанцовывается?  
Как его определить – когда есть фонетическое слово, а когда – нет?

Comment: По одной строке определить сложно, нужно 2-3-4. Стихотворный размер обычно определяют, пронумеровав все слоги и записав номер каждого слога как формулу.Цифровая формула хорея-1 3 5 7 9, ямба-2 4 6 8...,дактиля-1 4 7 10...,амфибрахия-2 5 8 11...,анапеста-3 6 9  12...Тогда вырисовывается полная картина, ритмический рисунок. Если встречаются пиррихии и спондеи (единичные пропуски или лишние ударения)-это нормально, если это как правило, постоянно, бывает объединение в одно фонетическое слово по задумке автора, а если полный сбой, разноброд при повторении количества слогов - тоническая система.

Comment: Спасибо, что Вы тратите на меня столько времени, но мы говорим о разных вещах. Поверьте, я умею определять стихотворный размер.   

Единственное, что я хочу выяснить - почему в приведенном 4-стишии в первой стопе третьей строки "моё счастье" образовывает фонетическое слово, а, скажем, "в углу счастье" - нет. Причём в обоих случаях формально стопа записывается как "-//" (безударный-ударный-ударный слоги).